# Pin "View Local Services" to Windows 7 Taskbar? 

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, services

I have to view the Windows services often and would like to pin the "View Local Services" to the Windows 7 taskbar somehow. It doesn't work when I try to drag it from the start menu, nor can I drag a shortcut to it.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

Right-Click the Services icon under *Start Menu->Administrative Tools*, and select **Pin to Taskbar** from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Perfect! This will be helpful for other things too.

Comment: Indeed. Note also the Pin to Start Menu item on that drop menu. And also note you can do this to about any shortcut or executable. If you right-click an executable under Windows Explorer for instance, you can select any of these two options which will generate a shortcut for you and immediately pin it.

Comment: Works in Windows 10, too. Open the Start Menu, start typing to search for your program, right click and pin to Start Menu or Taskbar.

Answer (score 3):

In Administrative Tools you can right click the icon and pin it directly to the taskbar.

**Or**

Right click on desktop -> New shortcut

point it to `services.msc` and pin to taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

This was different on my machine, which is Windows 8.1 Pro. Here's what I had to do to enable Administrative Tools to be shown in the metro Apps screen (as well as in the Windows search results):

1. Go to the Start screen
2. Open the Charms bar (WinKey + C is one way)
3. Go to Settings -> Tiles
4. Enable "Show Administrative Tools"